# Kubernetes with Google Cloud DNS

Tags: internal-dns, containers, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Using a Google Container Engine cluster running Kubernetes, what would the process be in order to point http://mydomain.co.uk onto a LoadBalanced ReplicationController?

I'm aware Kubernetes supports SkyDNS - how would I go about delegating Google Cloud DNS for a domain name onto the internal Kubernetes cluster DNS service?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to create a [service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/) that maps onto the pods in your replication controller and then expose that service outside of your cluster. You have two options to expose your web service externally:

1. [Set your service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-loadbalancer) to be `type: LoadBalancer` which will provision a [Network load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/).
2. Use the [ingress support](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) in Kubernetes to create an [HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/).

The end result of either option is that you will have a public IP address that is routed to the service backed by your replication controller.

Once you have that IP address, you will need to manually configure a DNS record to point your domain name at the IP address.

Comment: [This article](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) is a nice tutorial on how to deploy an ingress

Answer (score 0):

To automatically create DNS records for your services on GCP or AWS you can use [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns).

With it, you can set DNS names in your service annotations like this:

```
external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: your-service.external-dns-test.gcp.your-domain.com.
```